# Keeping build directories consistent with a docker container that ignores test dir while compiling from typescript

Tags: javascript, docker, typescript

We have a typescript app that lives in `/src`. We have tests that live in `/tests`. Locally, when we run TSC, it compiles both and deposits them to `/dist/src` and `/dist/test` respectively.

We also have a Dockerconfig that tells docker to ignore a bunch of dev files including `/tests`. When Docker runs `tsc`, it only sees `/src` and so it deposits all of `/src` to `/dist` -- meaning that when we have -- for example -- a /services folder that gets compiled to `/dist/src/services/whatever.js` locally; we see it at `/dist/services/whatever.js` in our container.

Our dockerfiles are small, they just run TSC and set entrypoints. Do we need to be more explicit with our dockerfiles? Is this a problem that people have found elegant solutions for?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without knowing exactly what directories are being mounted, and where in the docker container, but this sounds like a problem that should be solved with `tsconfig.json`, possibly with some creative use of the docker files if necessary.

For example, I have a dockerfile for `tsc` and it looks about like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && apk add nodejs && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN npm install -g typescript@~1.6
RUN mkdir /tsc
WORKDIR /tsc

ENTRYPOINT ["tsc"]
```

This container will be executed like this:

```
docker run tsc -v "./:/tsc"
```

And if my directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── tsconfig.json
├── dist
├── src
├── test
```

Then I see a few different possibilities for `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist/src"
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "exclude": ["test"]
}
```